# How to find the factors of all the numbers in a list in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to find the factors of all the numbers in a list. I have written my code but it does not work at all. I am new to Python and would appreciate any help. Here's my code:

```
n = [3,4,5]
for i in n:
    if i%n == 0:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print the factors for each of the numbers in your list. First we will go through each of the numbers, assume one of these numbers is 4. Then we will go through [1,2,3,4] and find out which of these is a factor of 4. Turns out its [1,2,4].

```
n = [3,4,5]
for i in n:
    print('Factors of ', i)
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if i%j == 0:
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

See, First, you are initializing the list as `n = [3,4,5]` and then for finding the factors what you are doing is dividing each element by the list.

when you write `i in n` so for every iteration your `i` will have the `value` of your `list's ith` element. As you are finding the factors, you are going to need another loop to iterate and check whether the numbers from `1 to your element in the list` can divide or not.

basic approach would be:

```
n = [3,4,5]
for i in n:
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if(i%j==0):
            print(j)
```